# Math.pow returning 0 in calc

Tags: javascript

I'm making a calculator currently and I'm running into an issue with one of the functions, specifically x^y, it keeps returning 0 and not even seeming to run the setInterval at all, though it runs without the if function around it. fn is for which function its using which is x^y, and vi is just a tool in the calculator to distinguish which number you are changing as in reactant, or reactant2, reactants are the 2 numbers that are squared against each other in this case. (this is only the portion of the code with the problem)

```
        function click15(){
    if (reactant > 0) {
    reactant = parseFloat(reactant);
}
if (reactant2 > 0) {
    reactant2 = parseFloat(reactant2);
}

if (fn === 0) {
    product = reactant / reactant2;
} else if (fn === 1) {
    product = reactant * reactant2;

} else if (fn === 2) {
    product = reactant - reactant2;

} else if (fn === 3) {
    product = reactant + reactant2;

} else if (fn === 4) {
    if (vi === 0) {
        vi = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (vi === 0) {
            product = (Math.pow(reactant, reactant2));
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 4);
}
}

    reactant = product;
    product = 0;
    reactant2 = "0";
    vir = 0;
    vir2 = 0;
    vi = 0;
    di1 = 0;
    di2 = 0;
    fn = -1;
}
```

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.

Comment: I restricted it because it was quite long and kind of tbh (being a noob) "messy." But i will put the complete code in it.

Comment: i understand why he wanted MCVE, when the = sign is pressed vi is set to 0, this allows the user to type what y is in x^y, im putting all the code in it now but its about 400 lines

Comment: @Benn MCVE != "All the code"

Comment: so should i set it to be longer then 4ms? what should i change

Comment: Ok robby, i only added the  "=" function, this shows the process of how it calculates, it will set product to reactant to allow the user to calculate when they want to calculate next. why is this specific function not working but fn 3 2 and 1 do work?

Comment: @JaromandaX it seems that it breaks down because of the if around the serInterval, the setInterval works without the if, but it is crucial for the funciton to work

Comment: 1/2, jaromandaX, it should calculate what the new 1st number is so that the next number can be calculated @ reactant = product

Comment: So is there a method you can suggest for this to work synchronously then?

Comment: Well, why I do it that way is because if I just press x^y and it does it your way, the y value has not been entered, so I use setInterval to wait until the y value has been entered and "=" has been hit.

Comment: so how does `+` work?

Comment: oh my goodness i'm such a smurf, your right, I can just use regular product = (Math.pow(reactant, reactant2)); Thanks for the help.